# Updating versions in multi-module Maven project

Tags: maven-3

I am trying to release our multi-module Maven project and I can't figure out how to properly update the version numbers in our POMs.

The maven release plugin doesn't update versions in the parent POM dependencyManagement section - that seems to be a known bug.

I tried to use the versions plugin, but I have two issues with that:

- the plugin only updates my toplevel POM; probably because the multi-module project POM is *not* the paremt POM of the modules's POMs
- more significantly, how can I mimic the behavior of the release plugin to automatically compute the versions to set (e.g. 1.0.0) from the current version in the POMs (e.g. 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)... without giong into perl scripting?

Any suggestion that doesn't involve scripting, and doesn't require me to declare dependency versions outside of dependencyManagement would be very appreciated!

Here are the 4 POMs (module POMs in their module subdirectory):

```
============ pom-parent.xml ==================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
                <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

============= multi-module pom: pom.xml ================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>dummy-parent</artifactId>
        <relativePath>pom-parent.xml</relativePath>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>
    <scm>
           <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svnserver.fairisaac.com:8443/nowhere</developerConnection>
       </scm>
</project>
```

============== module1 POM: module1/pom.xml ================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>dummy-parent</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../pom-parent.xml</relativePath>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

============= Module 2 POM: module2/pom.xml =============

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>dummy-parent</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../pom-parent.xml</relativePath>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

========= Edit ==============

... and it gets better, if I replace the explicit version in the dependencyManagement section with

```
<version>${project.version}</version>
```

... maven 3.0.4 fails with an NPE:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.478s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 12 12:09:08 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project multi-
module: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare failed. NullPointerExcep
tion -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. What are the odds, especially within a 3 hour span?

Comment: A fairly obvious need that Maven for some reason doesn't seem to be addressing... The issue with dependencyManagement seems to have been around for 5+ years, has been marked as fixed, then regressed, and I'm not even sure what the current status is officially.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, the first pom.xml you showed is outside your multi-module project. The maven-release-plugin will consider it an external dependency, thus it won't change the version.

But there is a flaw in your design, you have to move the

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

to your multi-module pom.

I'm assuming your idea is to declare the module version in one place and share it among all modules. So, the module version goes into the multi-module pom dependencyManagement.

Usually external poms like this are used to put company information, repository paths, things like this, and they are shared by many different projects.